# Why isn't the background color changing?

Tags: javascript, css

I have javacript code that simply runs

```
document.bgColor = "darkblue";
```

per

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Document.bgColor), however when I step throught the IE debugger, after executing that line the back ground color does not change.

Seems pretty straight forward.  I'm assuming that bgColor refers to the CSS attribute background-color under the element body?

I can post the surrounding code if that helps.

Comment: Have you read entire page you referencing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page has a large "deprecated" at the top of it. You should use the current method:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
```

This is stated in the MDN page you cited:

> *`document.bgColor` is deprecated in DOM Level 2 HTML. The recommended alternative is use of the CSS style background-color which can be accessed through the DOM with `document.body.style.backgroundColor`. Another alternative is `document.body.bgColor`, although this is also deprecated in HTML 4.01 in favor of the CSS alternative.*

Comment: Scanning to quickly.  Thanks, I should have caught that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, but the solution is to use standards-compliant techniques using the [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.style) object:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'darkblue';
```